# Explicitly Release Metal Texture

Tags: metal

Simple question that I can't find an answer to, On openGL there is a `glDeleteTextures(1, &t)` Obviously the model is quite drastically different but i'm wondering if Metal has the same need or requirement.

Are `MTLTexture`'s just released via reference counting or is there another way to release the texture and let the GPU clear it out of its caches as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MTLTexture` lifetimes are managed exactly like other objects: they are dealloc'ed when their refcount reaches 0 (whether that happens automatically with ARC/Swift or MRR under Obj-C). Objects that use textures, like command buffers, may retain textures while they are in use, affecting their lifetime, but most applications can happily ignore this.